# Slicing a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

The exercise in [this](http://scipy-lectures.github.com/) tutorial says:

> Generate a 10 x 3 array of random numbers (in range `[0,1]`). For each row, pick the number closest to `0.5`.
>
> Use `abs` and `argsort` to find the column `j` closest for each row.
>
> Use fancy indexing to extract the numbers. (Hint: `a[i,j]` – the array `i` must contain the row numbers corresponding to stuff in `j`.)

So I did everything, but I feel the slicing method I used (and the initialisation of `b`) is not pythonic at all:

```
a = np.random.rand(10,3)

mask = np.argmin(abs(a-0.5), axis = 1)

b = np.ones(mask.size)

for j in range(0,mask.size):
    b[j] = a[j,mask[j]]
```

What is the other way of doing this without using the `for` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10,3)
b = np.argmin(abs(a - .5), axis=1).choose(a.T)

# a
array([[ 0.97272372,  0.45351387,  0.19105835],
       [ 0.27895897,  0.12438789,  0.64857335],
       [ 0.05298066,  0.58122882,  0.805319  ],
       [ 0.39952727,  0.77728036,  0.65742471],
       [ 0.36522802,  0.06938552,  0.6595684 ],
       [ 0.9030323 ,  0.08965774,  0.01823633],
       [ 0.30996923,  0.53400339,  0.87600912],
       [ 0.17953532,  0.4888832 ,  0.0746074 ],
       [ 0.09052476,  0.47397504,  0.30317449],
       [ 0.31851577,  0.68135476,  0.38335483]])

# b
array([ 0.45351387,  0.64857335,  0.58122882,  0.39952727,  0.36522802,
        0.9030323 ,  0.53400339,  0.4888832 ,  0.47397504,  0.38335483])
```

Comment: Clever!  I would have used `b = a[range(len(mask)), mask]` instead (which I think is what the hint was suggesting) but this is neat.

Comment: Python never ceases to amaze me :D.
This is for people like me who need to see other examples on how `choose` works. [Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html?highlight=choose#numpy.choose)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't technically avoid the `for` loop, but a more pythonic way to write it would be to avoid the initial `np.ones` assignment and just use a list comprehension:

```
b = [a[j, mask[j]] for j in range(0, mask.size)]
```